# Why some stored procedures in MSSQL must be called with `master..` prepended while other can be called without?

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures

The MS SQL Server version in question is 8.

In the context of database other than master if I call stored procedures from master database, for some of them I must append `master..` prefix (otherwise I get *Could not find stored procedure 'procname'* error), for some of them I don't.
For example, I can call --

```
EXEC sp_addlogin 'user' 'pass';
```

-- and it works, but --

```
EXEC xp_cmdshell 'command';
```

-- doesn't. I have to prepend `master..` for it to work --

```
EXEC master..xp_cmdshell 'command';
```

I may be wrong here but I observed that one have to add `master..` to only those stored procedures that start with `xp_` (as opposed to `sp_`).

Why do I have to call some of them with `master..` prepended while some of them can be called without?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Procedures in the master database whose name begin with `sp_` can be called in any other user database without having to add the `master..` prefix. Since procedures beginning with `xp_` don't follow that rule, you still need to add the `master..` prefix when calling them.

[See this link for more information.](http://sqlandme.com/2011/10/03/sql-server-marking-a-stored-procedure-as-system-object/)

Comment: I researched the subject a bit further. Having stored procedure marked as system object doesn't affect the way you call it. It makes procedure run in the context of the currently selected user database. I edited your answer to reflect this correction. I accept it if peer review approves my correction.

Comment: The edit reviewing naysayers rejected my edit. @John Hodge, please, edit your answer yourself and I'll mark it as accepted. I suggest the following answer ----- Procedures in the `master` database whose name begin with `sp_` can be called in any other user database without having to add the `master..` prefix.

Answer (score 0):

The `xp_` stands for extended stored procedures. They are stored in the `master` database.

The `sp_` are for "special". They are Microsoft-shipped procedures that exist in every database. You can see them in the Object Explorer by going (Database Name) > Programmability > Stored Procedures > System Stored Procedures. Because they are in the same database as your query, you don't need to add `master..`

As a side note, it would be wise to NOT name your own stored procedures with `sp_...`. See explanation [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd172115%28v=vs.100%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396).

Comment: I've read a couple of articles since yesterday and seen people call them *special*. The actual name MS uses for `sp_` prefixed procs is *system* stored procedures. Even under your link they call them so =).

Comment: It was a old name from the days of SQL Server 2000. I'm an old bluff! But anyhow, the best practice is to always call your stored procedures with the schema. Something like `EXEC dbo.mySproc` or `EXEC sys.sp_addlogin`. And avoid the `sp_` prefix.

Comment: The confusion MS adds with those `xp_` and `sp_` prefixes is that procs with both prefixes can be found in both *Stored Procedures* branch (procs written in T-SQL) and *Extended Stored Procedures* branch (procs written in some unmanaged language in form of DLL). -- Speaking of MS SQL Server 2012 here.